# Android: Alignment of Elements inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I am currently building a custom Layout for an item in a ListView. First of all, here is the current XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textGameName"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textRuleName"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textLanguageName"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageAction"
        android:src="@mipmap/action_required"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageNext"
        android:src="@mipmap/button_list_enter"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically, what i want: I want the two ImageViews always be as far on the right as possible and the LinearLayout with the 3 TextViews inside shall use the whole remaining Space. In the android studio editor I am able to get the desired result, but as soon as I run it on Android (mine is 4.4.2) the LinearLayout is not expanded and the buttons are next to the texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this layout to achieve the desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageAction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textGameName"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textRuleName"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textLanguageName"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageAction"
        android:src="@mipmap/action_required"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageNext" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageNext"
        android:src="@mipmap/button_list_enter"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to adjust it just a little bit to fit my needs: The images needed width = wrap_content and height = fill_parent.

Comment: Ive looked into this now in a bit of detail. I knew that the rightOf existed, but somehow forgot it an Android Studio seems to just use it, if youre moving the left one to the right. Maybe it would be better to start writing xml instead of using the editor.

Answer (score 1):

does this help ? if it doesn't give me a picture of how the item should be

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textGameName"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textRuleName"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textLanguageName"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageNext"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageAction"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLeft"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linRight"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGameName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRuleName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textLanguageName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageAction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```